Convergence failure of a GAN with good generated result
I am struggling with an uncommon result (for me) that I cannot understand.
I have a Conditional GAN trained. The metrics I am monitoring during the training process are the losses of D and G (binary-cross entropy) and the Fidelity (the degree of similarity between two matrices). This metric when close to 1 is good and close to 0 is bad.
Fidelity is continuously rising which means that the matrices being generated by the network are becoming closer and closer to my target:

But the losses:

Why is that? Is something wrong or is this acceptable?
My Generator generated a matrix that is 99.99% close to the target matrix but the Discriminator is being perfect on discriminating between the generated and the real one?
Look at the generated sample, it is almost a ctr+c ctr+v from the original:

Generator loss going up and up while discriminator loss going close to zero doesn't mean convergence failure? From my understanding on convergence failure, this is the case, but it also means that the Generator is generating crap. But here this is not the case, I have:

big generator loss
very low discriminator loss
very good generated sample

Am I not getting something?

If you are using a cGAN, your cost (loss) function is of the form:
$$J(G,D) = min_G max_D E_x \log(D(x|y)) + E_z \log(1-D(G(z|y)))$$
so assuming you are using a discriminator that maps to the interval [0,1], your loss is on the interval $[-\infty,0]$. Your loss graph seems to have the negative of this.
Your log discriminator loss is converging to zero, so the discriminator values are converging to 1 for the true samples. On the other hand, your generator loss is not converging and seems to be increasing in variance. The generated PDF matrix is clearly very close to the data PDF matrix, so your cGAN has attained a useful parameter setting. If you were expecting convergence to some kind of optimum, it is necessary to know a little more about your experiment, and, in particular, about the dimensions of the data samples $n_x$ and of the latent variable $n_z$ that is your generator input.
The convergence results for the original GAN [Ref 1], are based on a hidden assumption, viz. $n_z \geq n_x$.  When this dimensional requirement is satisfied, one can expect that the discriminator and generator losses will converge to the values predicted in the 2014 paper, i.e., the so-called Nash equilibrium values of log(2) for the generator and log(4) for the discriminator. When the dimension of the data exceeds that of the latent variable, which is often the case in practice, the optimal discriminator (Proposition 1 of [1]) does not exist. The reasoning for this is contained at the end of section II of a paper published in the IEEE Access [2]. The gist of the argument is that when $n_z < n_x$, the generator output PDF contains delta functions. This precludes the integrand in the loss function from being continuously differentiable in the integration variable, preventing in turn the application of variational calculus on which Proposition 1 of [1] is based.
Another conclusion from [2] is that convergence does not occur to a saddle point (Nash equilibrium) but to a plateau where the gradients vanish. Depending on whether an optimal discriminator or generator is preferred (usually the optimal generator is what is wanted so as to emulate the data distribution), it is advisable to apply an early stopping criterion. It also bears mentioning that the implementation of GANs is usually based on {\em stochastic} gradient ascent descent (SGAD) to approximate the expectations in the cost function. This is an inherently noisy process particularly in higher dimensional spaces.
Further evidence is provided in reference [3] by Qin et al. They present simulations for a 2-D Gaussian mixture with $n_z = 32$, $n_x = 2$; and for the CIFAR-10 data set, which has $n_z = 128$, $n_x = 3072$. In the first case $n_z \geq n_x$ and the generator and discriminator losses converge to the Nash equilibrium values. In the second case $n_z < n_x$ and convergence does not occur within 1.2 million steps.
[1] "Generative Adversarial Nets", I. Goodfellow, J. Pouget-Abadie, M. Mirza, B. Xu, D. Warde-Farley, S. Ozair, A. Courville, and Y. Bengio. Advances in Neural Info. Proc. Systems 27, pages 2672–2680, 2014.
[2] "Convergence and Optimality Analysis of Low-Dimensional Generative Adversarial Networks Using Error Function Integrals"
available at  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/356815736_Convergence_and_Optimality_Analysis_of_Low-Dimensional_Generative_Adversarial_Networks_using_Error_Function_Integrals
[3] "Training Generative Adversarial Networks by Solving Ordinary Differential Equations", C. Qin, Y. Wu, J. T. Springenberg, A. Brock, J. Donahue, T. P. Lillicrap, and P. Kohli, 2020.
